# How to switch themes from an app that imports a published storybook library with themes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, themes, storybook

I have created themes in my storybook component library. Wanted to know how can I switch between themes after importing the library in my new application.
For example I want a light theme from story book before login and once the use logs in I want it to switch to dark theme.

I have created themes in the storybook component library and also able to switch between them in the storybook but unable to do it via my application which import the story book elements.